# Custom window chrome designtime support

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have my own custom control library project and one of the controls inside this library is Zune software like window. inside my WPF application I use this custom window control instead of default window. everything shows up as it supposed to show when I run my application, but the problem is that at design time, inside visual studio 2012 it still shows default window. what I would like to be able to to is to have the same zune software style at design time. what are the ways and how can I achieve this?

generally what I am trying to achieve is something like https://fluent.codeplex.com/ where instead of deriving window from base class all u have to do is to define window in this way

```
<Fluent:Ribbon>
<Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="Home">
    <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Clipboard">
        <Fluent:SplitButton Text="Paste" Icon="Images\Paste.png" LargeIcon="Images\PasteLarge.png">
        ...
     </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
     <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox x:Name="Font" ....
</Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

[image: DesignView]

This is my own custom code, but it's probably similar to the http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell library if you are looking for a more official source.

The main window is derived from an existing window, or in this case a [NavigationWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow.aspx)

```
namespace Centivus.WPF
{
    [TemplatePartAttribute(Name = "PART_SearchTextBox", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    public class SearchableNavigationWindow : NavigationWindow
    {
        ...
```

and its styled via a template

```
<!-- Custom NavigationWindow UI -->
<Style x:Key="Win7NavigationWindow" TargetType="{x:Type local:SearchableNavigationWindow}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="glass:GlassEffect.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="glass:GlassEffect.Thickness">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Thickness Top="35"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

                <DockPanel x:Name="mainDock"  LastChildFill="True" >
                    <!-- The border is used to compute the rendered height with margins.
                                topBar contents will be displayed on the extended glass frame.-->
...
```

The only clever part to this is the use of an attached property to apply glass which I would assume you are doing something incredibly similar if you are using custom chrome

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Centivus.WPF.Glass
{
    public class GlassEffect
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
             DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled",
             typeof(Boolean), typeof(GlassEffect),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnIsEnabledChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ThicknessProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Thickness",
            typeof(Thickness), typeof(GlassEffect));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GlassBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GlassBackground",
            typeof(Brush), typeof(GlassEffect));


        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static void SetGlassBackground(DependencyObject element, Brush value)
        {
            element.SetValue(GlassBackgroundProperty, value);
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static Brush GetGlassBackground(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (Brush)element.GetValue(GlassBackgroundProperty);
        }


        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static void SetThickness(DependencyObject element, Thickness value)
        {
            element.SetValue(ThicknessProperty, value);
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static Thickness GetThickness(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (Thickness)element.GetValue(ThicknessProperty);
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject element, Boolean value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static Boolean GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (Boolean)element.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if ((bool)args.NewValue == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Window wnd = (Window)obj;
                    wnd.Activated += new EventHandler(wnd_Activated);
                    wnd.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(wnd_Loaded);
                    wnd.Deactivated += new EventHandler(wnd_Deactivated);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Oh well, we tried
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Window wnd = (Window)obj;
                    wnd.Activated -= new EventHandler(wnd_Activated);
                    wnd.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(wnd_Loaded);
                    wnd.Deactivated -= new EventHandler(wnd_Deactivated);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        static void wnd_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyGlass((Window)sender);
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        static void wnd_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            ApplyGlass((Window)sender);
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        static void wnd_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            ApplyGlass((Window)sender);
        }


        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        private static void ApplyGlass(Window window)
        {
            try
            {
                // Obtain the window handle for WPF application
                IntPtr mainWindowPtr = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
                HwndSource mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(mainWindowPtr);

                // Get System Dpi
                System.Drawing.Graphics desktop = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(mainWindowPtr);
                float DesktopDpiX = desktop.DpiX;
                float DesktopDpiY = desktop.DpiY;

                // Set Margins
                GlassEffect.MARGINS margins = new GlassEffect.MARGINS();
                Thickness thickness = GetThickness(window);//new Thickness();

                // Extend glass frame into client area
                // Note that the default desktop Dpi is 96dpi. The  margins are
                // adjusted for the system Dpi.
                margins.cxLeftWidth = Convert.ToInt32(thickness.Left * (DesktopDpiX / 96) + 0.5);
                margins.cxRightWidth = Convert.ToInt32(thickness.Right * (DesktopDpiX / 96) + 0.5);
                margins.cyTopHeight = Convert.ToInt32((thickness.Top * DesktopDpiX / 96) + 0.5);
                margins.cyBottomHeight = Convert.ToInt32(thickness.Bottom * (DesktopDpiX / 96) + 0.5);

                int hr = GlassEffect.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(mainWindowSrc.Handle, ref margins);
                //
                if (hr < 0)
                {
                    //DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea Failed      
                    if(window.IsActive)
                        SetGlassBackground(window, SystemColors.GradientActiveCaptionBrush);
                    else
                        SetGlassBackground(window, SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaptionBrush);
                }
                else
                {
                    mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    SetGlassBackground(window, Brushes.Transparent);
                }


            }
            // If not Vista, paint background white.
            catch (DllNotFoundException)
            {
                SetGlassBackground(window, SystemColors.ControlBrush);
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MARGINS
        {
            public int cxLeftWidth;      // width of left border that retains its size
            public int cxRightWidth;     // width of right border that retains its size
            public int cyTopHeight;      // height of top border that retains its size
            public int cyBottomHeight;   // height of bottom border that retains its size
        };


        [DllImport("DwmApi.dll")]
        public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(
            IntPtr hwnd,
            ref MARGINS pMarInset);
    }
}
```

There's a little more information also at http://alski.net/post/2012/01/13/WPF-Wizards-part-2-Glass.aspx

Comment: A provided sample link and my problem is not related to the glass effect. I am relaying on some native code as well but the only problem I have is to show window inside Visual studio in the same way as it is shown when I run application.

Comment: Well that's kind of my point there's nothing clever doing that, just the styling if the wimdow. I believe it's simply a feature of VS2012. I'm not sure VS2019 ever did it.

Comment: Sorry but do you mean VS2010? I have never header of VS2019. and I am currently using VS 2012. and I forgot to mention that, If I use Create that control inside same project as application and use it as UserControl it works the problem is when this control is in a separate class library. this is when design time support is not provided.